# Why is diff showing that there is a difference in these two files?

Tags: diff

For some reason, diff is not responding as expected to the -w option; two files, both of which are identical except for a single new line at the end of the XML header.

I'm invoking diff with the -w option, like so:

```
diff -w old_file.xml new_file.xml
```

`# head -n4 old_file.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><survey audio_access_number="" custom="" name="test_conditionFormula" title="" type="CATI"><section id="1" loopover="None" notes="" startrecording="true" title="1">
    <page id="1_Q1" loopover="None" notes="" title="1_Q1"><question id="Q1" number="Q1" style="vertical" text="1" uid="94">
        <single id="single_409" number_response_columns="1" response_list="Q1_L1"/>
        <instructions>Please select one</instructions>
```

`# head -n4 new_file.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<survey audio_access_number="" custom="" name="test_conditionFormula" title="" type="CATI"><section id="1" loopover="None" notes="" startrecording="true" title="1">
    <page id="1_Q1" loopover="None" notes="" title="1_Q1"><question id="Q1" number="Q1" style="vertical" text="1" uid="94">
        <single id="single_409" number_response_columns="1" response_list="Q1_L1"/>
```

Why are these coming up as different, given the flag to diff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diff compares line-by-line. So a newline isn't whitespace within a line

> -w
>
> Ignore white space when comparing
>   lines.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff

Comment: I've also tried '-w -B', '-w --ignore-all-space', '-w -b -B --ignore-all-space' and any other mix of those you can imagine.

Comment: yes, you can't do it with diff. Diff compares line-by-line, and you have a file where the lines are different. What's the actual test you want to run? You could concatenate all lines into one and then test the result of that? (with 'cmp'not 'diff' though, as the diff you have may have line length restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

From diff manual:

```
 -w  --ignore-all-space
              Ignore all white space.
```

Seems like newlines aren't whitespace.

If this doesn't help, check files with xxd, one of them might have UTF8 header or some similar invisible binary problem.